# Announcement: Retiring my role as a pro-tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'd like to inform that, effective tomorrow, I'm retiring my role as a pro-tem moderator here at *Money*.

This decision wasn't easy. It's been a great four years founding and helping grow this community, but I've come to the conclusion that right now I need to focus more on my family and my business.

Moreover, *Money* is now in great shape.  I owe a big thanks to my moderator teammates ([@AlexB](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/815/alex-b), [@C.Ross](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/312/c-ross), [@GeorgeMarian](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/868/george-marian), [@MrChrister](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/91/mrchrister)), and a big thanks to the community as well as the [***many***](https://money.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) individual contributors who helped establish personal finance as a successful topic in the Stack Exchange network.  It's been fun and I've learned a lot from so many of you.

I do intend to remain on as regular user, asking & answering questions from time to time, and I continue to look forward to this site being launched as a full-fledged Stack Exchange site — [very soon](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/801/design-for-personal-finance-money)!

All the best.

Comment: Too Bad. Is it really required to step down. Even being a moderator one can continue without spending too much time. After spending 4 yrs to build this, quitting before its gone live sound to early. If you have made up your mind. Good Luck :)

Comment: @Dheer Thanks. The truth is: checking the site frequently has become a hard habit to break. I couldn't take a back seat without giving up moderator privileges -- I actually already tried that and failed. :)

Comment: Sorry to see you go Chris. Thanks for all your work!

Comment: You'll be missed as a moderator, but good to hear that you'll be sticking around. As the originator of the idea for money.SE, I'm sure that many of us share my sentiment that you've made it a great environment for all of us.

Comment: @JohnBensin Thanks! My #1 goal was to establish an inclusive site. I hope I've succeeded and that it continues to grow that way.

Comment: Not sure why people are upvoting this question. On Meta upvoting something means that you like the idea. I have downvoted this :)

Comment: I'm upvoting my support for a great moderator. You're not going to change his mind. We already tried. :P

Comment: @Dheer News: *Money* is the next SE site to graduate. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11562316#11562316

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Great News. Finally :)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I hope you will accomplish your goals with family and business. Thank you for herding us along to Money SE graduation. Please visit regularly? I will miss you.                          Your friend, here and on Twitter, Ellie

Comment: @FeralOink Thank you. And yes, I'll be visiting regularly.

Answer (score 14):

Chris,

I was really sorry to hear about your retirement. I know it has been a long and arduous road for you and Personal Finance & Money — waiting for your four-year anniversary is a touching gesture — but know that all the hard work has really paid off. With about 5,000 visitors per day (and quality better than ever), you have really created one great site here! I'd like to thank you personally for the contribution you made in getting this site and this community to graduation, and know that you contribution and your leadership will be missed.

I hope you will continue to enjoy this site. If you ever wish to take on a more-leading role again, I hope you will consider running again in an upcoming election.  But if you choose not to stick around, know that the contribution you made to this community will not be forgotten.

Take care, kick back, and enjoy your life as a civilian. And from myself and the staff at Stack Exchange — **Thank you!**

Comment: Thanks! And you're welcome. I do intend to stick around, and I'll certainly be *voting* in the first post-graduation election, but that'll be it, for now :)

Answer (score 10):

Chris, it was your personal invitation that brought me here. And my own compulsive nature that's made me the highest scoring poster. This is a great site you've created and a place where we can really make a difference. The idea of 'making the world a better place one person at a time' is pretty real for me, as I know that the help we offer is both free and yet priceless. Keep in touch.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I appreciate it. I'll be around. My own compulsive nature will see to that :)