# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/801/design-for-personal-finance-money).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://cdn.sstatic.net/money/img/favicon.ico

http://cdn.sstatic.net/moneymeta/img/favicon.ico

I've made some design tweaks since the initial design concepts posted, mostly for readability reasons. I re-arranged the logo and top nav links so they're more readable,

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

If you have questions about the privilege changes post launch, please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

Comment: Jin, it's really nice. No, I mean it - this design is *money!*

Comment: Woohoo!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @jin, I got so excited, I went back to my old life for a second and answered an option question!

Comment: Very nice. Well done!

Comment: The favicon links are broken.

Answer (score 11):

Excellent work!  I am very excited to see the change and have our own special logo

Things are gonna starting happenin' here now....

Comment: The new phone book is here!  The new phone book is here!