# Issue with new design: The "ASK QUESTION" link doesn't stand out. New users will not notice it

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions

The link to **ask a new question** is lost somewhere in the menu. It doesn't attract any attention.

A new user was trying to post a question, but since it wasn't so obvious to him how to do it, he was posting his question as an answer to similar questions, and [got frustrated and furious when those got deleted](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24199/corporate-structure-for-sole-purpose-of-gambling-llc-vs-s-corp/28680#28680).

While the new interface is nice and shiny, it should be usable and understandable by the **new** uninformed users. They don't need to *look for* the ASK QUESTION button, they should *see* it. Basic UX.

---

To add insult to injury, [the "tour"](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) doesn't even show this button. It has its own "Ask Question" button at the end, but after the tour the new user will still not know how to ask a question.

Please fix! kthx

Answer (score 4):

I had pointed this out 7 months ago when we were asked for **feedback** on the design. Refer to my [earlier answer](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/801/design-for-personal-finance-money/806#806), which had 13 up-votes. Quote:

> 3. I suggest making the **"Ask Question"** link more prominent. I see the underline on close inspection, but even so, the link doesn't stand out
>   as much as it ought to, perhaps owing to the all-caps used for all the
>   links on that line. Maybe lighten the other links, or darken this one?
>   Or something else to help it stand out more. It stands out well enough
>   in the beta theme we have now because the font weight is obviously
>   heavier.

What's worse: In the original design proposal, the links were *under* the logo, and centered. Now, they are positioned on the same line as the logo, more to the right. This means that "Ask Question" is also likely to be **hidden** if the user doesn't have their browser window sized wide enough.  (Stack Overflow also has this issue, but at least the "Ask Question" link there is set aside far enough to the right that it stands out when the window *is* wide enough.)

So, I agree. Needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I apologized to our newest Internet-Furious member.  I took some shortcuts because I was in a rush and that wasn't fair.

Secondly, I totally agree.  Just looking at a few other sites, the ASK QUESTION button is at least set apart, and often a different color.

We probably need to have our button on a different line because of the width of the logo - I defer to designers.

Comment: I think that particular user is lost and will not come back, but we do need to make it more obvious and clear for others.